# How add nginx-ingress custom health check behind a nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a nginx server outside kubernetes. `nginx -> nginx ingress`. I want know how add a custom health check path `/health/status` to nginx ingress.

Comment: You want to add health check to a nginx server running outside kubernetes for the nginx Ingress controller running inside kubernetes?

Comment: yes. I want add health check in front nginx server

Answer (score 1):

*This question is almost certainly solving the wrong problem, but in the spirit of answering what was asked:*

You can expose the Ingress `/healthz` to the outside world:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-health
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector: # whatever
  ports:
  - name: healthz
    port: 80
    targetPort: 10254
---
kind: Ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: elb-1234.example.com
    http:
      path: /healthz
      backend:
        serviceName: ingress-nginx-health
        servicePort: healthz
```

Because if your Ingress controller falls over, it will for sure stop answering its own healthz check

Comment: Thanks you answer, but I want a L3 layer health check without L7, only by ip check.

Comment: Welp, if you don't ask the right question, you don't get the right answer. Good luck in your journey